# Unity 3D C# code, overloads computer no error

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

issue is with the ShowPath(); method as it keeps overloading this code is supposed to collect the shortest route then highlight it once it has found both start and end tile it calculates the shortest route to the beggining

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PathfindingClass
{
    public class pathFinding
    {
            public  bool startFound = false;
    public TileClass.Tile[,] grid = new TileClass.Tile[AStarPath.gridWidth,AStarPath.gridHeight];
    public Vector2 startTile;
    public Vector2 endTile;
    public Vector2 currentTile;

    // create a list that stores the checked tiles
    List<Vector2> openList = new List<Vector2>();
    List<Vector2> closedList = new List<Vector2>();

    public pathFinding (TileClass.Tile[,] grid)
    {
        this.grid = grid;

    }

    public void SearchPath(Vector2 startTile, Vector2 endTile){
        this.startTile = startTile;
        this.endTile = endTile;

        #region Path Validation
        bool canSearch = true;

        if(grid[(int)startTile.x,(int)startTile.y].walkable ==false){
        canSearch = false;
            Console.WriteLine("the start square is not walkable");
        }
        if(grid[(int)endTile.x,(int)endTile.y].walkable ==false){
        canSearch = false;
            Console.WriteLine("the end square is not walkable");
        }

        #endregion

        if(canSearch){
            //add the starting tile to the open list
        openList.Add(startTile);    
            currentTile = new Vector2(-1,-1);

            //while the open list is not empty
            while(openList.Count > 0){
                currentTile = getTyleWithLowestTotal(openList);

                //if the current tile is the end tile stop searching
                if((int)currentTile.x == (int)endTile.x && (int)currentTile.y == (int)endTile.y  ){
                //  if((int)currentTile.x == (int)endTile.x){
                        break;
                    //}
                }else{
                    openList.Remove(currentTile);
                    closedList.Add(currentTile);

                    //get all the adjacent tiles
                    List<Vector2> adjacentTiles = getAdjacentTiles(currentTile);

                    foreach(Vector2 adjacentTile in adjacentTiles){
                    // the adjacent tile is not aloude within eith of the open or closed lists
                        if(!openList.Contains(adjacentTile)){
                            if(!closedList.Contains(adjacentTile)){
                                // move it to the open list
                                openList.Add(adjacentTile);

                                TileClass.Tile tile = grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y];

                                tile.cost = grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y].cost+1;

                                //calculate the manhattan distance
                                tile.horistic = ManhattanDistance(adjacentTile);

                                //calculate the total cost
                                tile.total = tile.cost + tile.horistic;

                                tile.color = new Vector4(0,0,1,1);
                                tile.Y=2;
                                }
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        grid[(int)startTile.x,(int)startTile.y].color = Color.yellow;
        grid[(int)endTile.x,(int)endTile.y].color = Color.yellow;

        //Show the shortestPath

        ShowPath();
    }


    public void ShowPath(){
        Vector2 currentTile = endTile;
        List<Vector2> PathTiles = new List<Vector2>();

        while(!startFound){
        List<Vector2> adjacentTiles = getAdjacentTiles(currentTile);

            //check to  see what the used current tile is
            foreach(Vector2 adjacentTile in adjacentTiles){
                if(openList.Contains(adjacentTile) || closedList.Contains(adjacentTile)){

                    grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y].color = Color.yellow;

                    if(adjacentTile.x == startTile.x){
                        startFound = true;
                    break;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    }



    //calculate the manhattan distance
    public int ManhattanDistance(Vector2 adjacentTile){
    int manhattan = Math.Abs((int)( endTile.x - adjacentTile.x)) + Math.Abs((int)(endTile.y - adjacentTile.y)); 
        return manhattan;
    }

                    //check the adjacent tiles to the current tile
    public List<Vector2> getAdjacentTiles(Vector2 currentTile){
        List<Vector2> adjacentTiles = new List<Vector2>();
        Vector2 adjacentTile;

        //above
        adjacentTile = new Vector2(currentTile.x,currentTile.y+1);
        if(adjacentTile.y < AStarPath.gridHeight && grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y].walkable){
            adjacentTiles.Add(adjacentTile);
        }
                    //below
        adjacentTile = new Vector2(currentTile.x,currentTile.y-1);
        if(adjacentTile.y >= 0 && grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y].walkable){
            adjacentTiles.Add(adjacentTile);
        }
                    //right
        adjacentTile = new Vector2(currentTile.x +1,currentTile.y);
        if(adjacentTile.x < AStarPath.gridWidth && grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y].walkable){
            adjacentTiles.Add(adjacentTile);
        }
                    //left
        adjacentTile = new Vector2(currentTile.x -1,currentTile.y);
        if(adjacentTile.x >= 0 && grid[(int)adjacentTile.x,(int)adjacentTile.y].walkable){
            adjacentTiles.Add(adjacentTile);
        }

        //optional to add diagonal checking
        return adjacentTiles;
    }   

    // get the tiles with the lowest total value
    public Vector2 getTyleWithLowestTotal(List<Vector2> openList){
        //temp vars
        Vector2 tileWithLowestTotal = new Vector2(-1,-1);
        int lowestTotal = int.MaxValue;

        // search all the open tiles and get the tile with the lowest total cost
        foreach(Vector2 openTile in openList){
            if(grid[(int)openTile.x,(int)openTile.y].total <= lowestTotal){
            lowestTotal = grid[(int)openTile.x,(int)openTile.y].total;
                tileWithLowestTotal = grid[(int)openTile.x,(int)openTile.y].ID;
            }               
        }
    return tileWithLowestTotal;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: is `startFound` ever set to `true`?

Comment: In the while loop in ShowPath(), currentTile never changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Unity Pro? If so, you can use the profiler to find where it is spending more time. If not, you can run the `Debugger` in MonoDevelop: put some breakpoints in the code and press the `Debug` button; it will open another instance of Unity. Then you play the project and it will stop in your breakpoint. From that point, you can run step by step and see where it's locked. More information [here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Debugger.html).

Comment: yea sorry will have to put the latest code in unfortunatley i removed a heap as it was more then a few lines of code and was in a rush this morning cheers

Comment: ok thanks guys after a lot of digging and debugging the script was faltering at the while loop because the bool would never switch bit of a novice mistake but working well now the path finder script will be in the asset store for free soon =)

Comment: thank you for the edit it was the correct answer i used error debugging and the profiler to manage where the script was terminating eded up that my loop was lockedd because my horistic value was not calculating well rather was not being used so the script would never find the beggining block thanks your comments really helped